# Boost::karma compile error with GCC 6.3.0 but not 4.8.3

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I get compile error when I switch the same code from GCC 4.8.3 to 6.3.0 when using BOOST 1_55. Any help would be appreciated. TIH.

```
  cfg_printer_grammar() : cfg_printer_grammar::base_type( start )
  {
    using karma::lit;
    using karma::double_;
    using namespace karma::labels;

#if __cplusplus < 201103L
    typedef const double& ( std::complex<double>:: *accessor )() const;
#else
    typedef double ( std::complex<double>:: *accessor )() const;
#endif
    accessor ar = &std::complex<double>::real;
    accessor ai = &std::complex<double>::imag;

    quoted_string = lit( '"' ) << karma::string << lit( '"' );
    long_vector = lit( '[' )
                  << ( ( karma::long_ % lit( ", " ) ) | karma::eps )
                  << lit( ']' );
    value = (

      quoted_string
      | ( karma::lit( "0x" ) << hex_long )
      | complex_num
      | karma::double_
      | karma::long_
      | karma::bool_
      | complex_vector
      | double_vector
      | long_vector
      | value_vector
      );

    param_statement = karma::repeat( _r1 )[ lit( ' ' ) ]
                      << karma::string << " = " << value << ";";
```

Errors:

```
boost-1_55/boost/spirit/home/karma/auxiliary/lazy.hpp:167:13: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct boost::result_of<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::phoenix::composite<boost::phoenix::detail::function_eval<1>, boost::fusion::vector<boost::phoenix::value<boost::spirit::terminal<boost::spirit::tag::repeat> >, boost::spirit::attribute<1>, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_> > >(boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<const std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, boost::variant<boost::detail::variant::recursive_flag<std::basic_string<char> >, std::complex<double>, double, long unsigned int, long int, bool, std::vector<std::complex<double> >, std::vector<double>, std::vector<long int>, std::vector<boost::recursive_variant_>, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_> >&, boost::fusion::cons<int, boost::fusion::nil_> >, boost::fusion::vector0<> >)>'
             directive_expr_type;
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
boost-1_55/boost/spirit/home/karma/auxiliary/lazy.hpp:175:13: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct boost::result_of<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::phoenix::composite<boost::phoenix::detail::function_eval<1>, boost::fusion::vector<boost::phoenix::value<boost::spirit::terminal<boost::spirit::tag::repeat> >, boost::spirit::attribute<1>, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_> > >(boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<const std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, boost::variant<boost::detail::variant::recursive_flag<std::basic_string<char> >, std::complex<double>, double, long unsigned int, long int, bool, std::vector<std::complex<double> >, std::vector<double>, std::vector<long int>, std::vector<boost::recursive_variant_>, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_> >&, boost::fusion::cons<int, boost::fusion::nil_> >, boost::fusion::vector0<> >)>'
             expr_type;
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal selfcontained example of this problem?

Comment: I take it you cannot make it self-contained? Or did you miss the comment? I'm monitoring the question

Comment: Please provide a [mre].